# readtable start at specific row in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I read a file with `readtable` ([docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)) starting at row 6?

I tried the following but this only reads the first two columns (I have columns A:L):

```
opts = detectImportOptions(fileName);
opts.VariableNamesRange = 'A6';
opts.DataRange = 'A7';   

raw = readtable(fileName,opts,'ReadVariableNames',true)
```

When I do

```
opts.VariableNamesRange = 'A6:L6';
opts.DataRange = 'A7:L7';
```

I get the error message:

> Invalid 'VariableNamesRange'. The column size must match the number of
>   variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before setting the `VariableNamesRange` and `DataRange` fields of `opts`, try setting the `VariableNames` field to something like `opts.VariableNames = cellstr(['A':'L']')`.

A couple of notes on this:

1. The number of columns in the `VariableNamesRange` and `DataRange` fields needs to match the length of the `VariableNames` field. Check the results `detectImportOptions` to see how many columns it detected;
2. If you do this, then check the `VariableTypes` field to make sure that all variables are the correct type (`double` or `char`).